# How to tell if an object's class is exactly what you've specified? Usage of "is" keyword

Tags: c#, types

Say I have three classes

```
public class A { }
public class B: A { }
public class C: B { }
```

If I were to create an object of type `C objC = new C()` and use the `is` keyword to check the validity of the statement `objC is B` I would have the result of `true`. From what I can tell `is` only checks the validity of casting the given object instance to the specified type.

For a case in my application I have the need to know/compare the specific class of an object so that when given an object reference comparing it to some type results in true if and only if it is that type exactly.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: It sounds like your use case is based on a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.  `C` *is* an instance of `B`.

Comment: you can do objC.GetType() == typeof(C)

Comment: Object.ReferenceEquals(x.GetType(),y.GetType())

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for specific types using [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) and [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
objC.GetType() == typeof(B) //false
objC.GetType() == typeof(C) //true
```